# GDPR - website with no cookies, no analytics, no private data collection

Tags: gdpr

I'm building a website right now and I'm little bit concerned about GDPR and I hope you can help me out.

So, the website will be a blog with posts, product reviews and some affiliate links, I plan to receive some income from it, so you could say it will be a commercial website.

The thing is, I would like to avoid showing my real name on the website. Everything is legit, but it's connected to the adult industry so I would like to keep my real name private.

If I would use analytics or first/third-party cookies, I know I would have to disclose my name in the privacy policy as I would be Data Controller so I decided not to use any analytics or cookies on the website.

I would still have privacy policy where I would state that I'm not processing any personal data and I'm not sending it to some other website. There would also be an email so if someone wants to contact me with some questions, they can do that.

Would that make me compliant with the GDPR legislation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you'll still most likely be collecting what's considered personal information.  IP address is considered identifying, so most likely, that puts you in GDPR-compliance-land.

Why don't you use the name of your website as the controller?  Contact information as info@websitename.com.  As presumably a small business, you are afforded some leeway in the regulation.  While possibly not absolutely 100% compliant, it would make you pretty darned close.

I think a privacy policy would be a good thing for people visiting your site, and making it GDPR compliant is the right thing to do anyway.

Comment: Also, if your site contains external links you might want something that says you only put legit links in but you are not responsible for the content of external websites

Comment: The name of the website isn't a person, so it can't be a controller. It's either the individual, a group of individuals (in England an ordinary partnership), a body corporate (company), or several bodies corporate. Deriving income means declaring it for tax purposes, so it depends on your jurisdiction as to whether there are any other disclosure obligations. If you process personal data within the scope of the GDPR, the identity of the controller must be disclosed to data subjects when/before collecting their data, or within one month if receiving it indirectly, among other things.